# Error: Request Entity Too Large, Your client issued a request that was too large

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage, django-storage

I am using google cloud engine to run django application and cloud storage to save media files.
Looks like I can save files upto 2 Mega Bytes. But if I try to save large file I get this error

> Error: Request Entity Too Large, Your client issued a request that was too large.

I am using django-storages library to save files to google cloud. This is how I save it

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

obj.file.save('file_name', ContentFile('more content'))
```

In my settings.py file I played with  `GS_BLOB_CHUNK_SIZE = 256K` as explained  [here](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html). Though it takes time to save, but works on my local server, but doesn't on cloud engine.

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The official limit for requests is not 2MB but [32MB instead](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits). So to avoid this limitation you could provide the user with a [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#code-samples) so they have direct access to the bucket and can upload files without the 32 MB limitation.